# What is the most efficient way to loop through a text document and count pairs of text next to each other?

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, while-loop

1. So I'm new with coding and this is a little Python script I made a minute ago and I'm not sure if it's very efficient.
2. I'm not sure I formatted this question correctly anyway here is the script:

```py
# Counts the number of pairs (in this case every time 
# 1,6, and a period are next to each other)

counting = 0

# The variable for the array I put all the characters of 
# text in.

array = []

# The variable which counts the amount of characters in 
# the text document

arraycounter = 0

# For loop that goes through text document and puts it in 
# my array.

for x in open("/tmp/python_001.py/Info.txt", "r").read():
    array.append(x)

# While loop that goes through the array and if statement 
# that checks if 1, 6, and a period are next to each other

while arraycounter + 2 < len(array):
    if array[arraycounter] == '1' and array[arraycounter + 1] == '6' and 
    array[arraycounter + 2] == '.': 
        counting += 1
    arraycounter += 1
        
# Prints the counting variable

print(counting)
```

Comment: Your question would probably be clearer with a little well chosen sample text and your expected output for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an array, you can [slice the string to compare](https://stackoverflow.com/q/509211/5923139), and you can use [`range` to iterate](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_range.asp):

```py
with open("/tmp/python_001.py/Info.txt", "r") as f:
    contents = f.read()

count = 0
for i in range(len(contents) - 2):
    if contents[i:i + 3] == "16.":
        count += 1

print(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically, we read lines of a file as:

```
with open("....", "r") as file:
    result = file.readlines()
```

If you are looking for '16.' to appear in a string, you can just write:

```
if '16.' in my_string
   ...
```

If you think '16.' appears more than once in a string (and in your original code, you count multiple occurrences), you can use `find()` which tells you the first occurrence of a string inside another string (or -1) if it doesn't occur.  It also has a `start=` argument so you can skip over occurrences you've already found when looking for the next.